# Sorting ArrayList - JAVA

Tags: java, csv, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a csv file which includes 3 columns (name,gender,age) and it's irregular(not sorted). I have created a class which name is "Person" and add to a Araylist each column of the csv file by the Person object. Afterthat I wanted to sort this list however it's not sorting. The list occurs as the same the csv file. My code which I expected to sort is below. Could you please check why this code not sorting my list according to age.

```
Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
            
@Override
        
public int compare(Person first, Person second) {
                if (first.age < second.age) {
                    return first.age;
                } else {
                    return second.age;
                }
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
    enter code here
```

Kind Regards.

Comment: as per the javadocs *Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.*

Comment: You need to return something like `Integer.compare(first.age, second.age)` or simply do `first.age - second.age`. As Scary Wombat pointed out, you need to read the Javadoc on `Comparator`.

Comment: Can you please give some example and whats the result actually you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the if else condition.

```
    Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person first, Person second) {
            return first.getAge() - second.getAge();
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(persons, comparator);
```

OR

**Java 8**

Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));

Comment: Thank you so much   Subha Chandra ; as you typed my Final and Runnable Code :               
           Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Person first, Person second) {

                        return first.Age- second.Age;
              }
            };
                     Collections.sort(myList,comparator);

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

According to the Java doc,

```
Comparator#compare
```

Returns:
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.